# Order by numbers desc then by letters asc

Tags: sql-server

I have a varchar column and the current order is like this:

```
select name from table order by name

1value
2value
3value
Avalue
Bvalue
Cvalue
```

I want to order first by numbers desc and then by letters asc:

```
3value
2value
1value
Avalue
Bvalue
Cvalue
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Ideally you would *normalize* your data with a column for each discrete value, then suddently you issue is trivial; Is it always one character that's a number or can you have arbitrarily large numbers?

Comment: @Stu Can be also large numbers like 2012456somestringvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TRY_CAST and LEFT to achieve this.

```
SELECT * FROM
   #p
ORDER BY
-- Numeric first
TRY_CAST(LEFT(your_value,1) AS int) DESC,
-- If numeric, sort with a DESC
CASE WHEN
    TRY_CAST(LEFT(your_value,1) AS int) IS NOT NULL
THEN
    your_value
END DESC,
-- Otherwise, sort with an ASC
CASE WHEN
    TRY_CAST(LEFT(your_value,1) AS int) IS NULL
THEN
    your_value
END ASC;
```

Comment: `.` and `-` return `1` for `ISNUMERIC()`. Perhaps you should use `ORDER BY TRY_CAST(LEFT(your_value,1) AS int) DESC` instead

Comment: Good spot.   Didn't realise they did that unaccompanied.   Amended the answer.   Thanks.